# Does SQL guarantee that the results of a join will be grouped together?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

In SQL, when joining two tables, is the user guaranteed to have the resulting tuples grouped together?

E.g.: in the following example, would the result be consistently listed showing all the pets grouped by their owners?

TABLE OWNERS

```
ID OWNER_NAME
1  Alice
2  Bob
3  Carol
4  Dave
```

TABLE PETS

```
OWNER_ID PET_NAME
1        Furry
2        Doggy
2        Jonny
1        Ellie
3        Thunder
```

Query:

```
SELECT OWNER_NAME, PET_NAME
FROM OWNERS
JOIN PETS ON OWNERS.ID = PETS.OWNER_ID;
```

Result (?):

```
OWNER_NAME PET_NAME
Alice      Furry
Alice      Ellie
Bob        Doggy
Bob        Jonny
Carol      Thunder
```

Comment: It is not. You should use `order by` to guaranty this.

Comment: You write SQL to say *what you want*, not *how to do it*. So, if you want results in a particular order, that specification ought to appear in what you write (via `ORDER BY`) - otherwise, the optimizer is free to accomplish the job in whatever manner is most efficient for it to do so, so long as it produces the results you asked for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To guarantee order of the rows in the resulting dataset, you have to use `order by` keyword

```
select
    o.owner_name, p.pet_name
from owners as o
    inner join pets as p on p.owner_id = o.id
order by o.owner_name, p.pet_name
```

otherwise rows can be in any order (for example SQL engine can order rows internally to join tables together and then return rows in that order)